# Is there a "info libc" for c++?

Tags: manpage, info

With `info libc` you have a offline copy of the C Reference Library. Is there a version of this for C++?

When I use `info libstdc++` nothing happens, so I assume a different name is used for the C++ version.

Comment: Maybe `libc++`? Found some [info here](https://libcxx.llvm.org/)